# Telerik RadGrid: Show column only in edit mode?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I'd like to "hide" one column in my RadGrid and only have it show when I'm in edit mode.  I tried just moving it into the edit item template, but that didn't work at all.

Any suggestions would be deeply appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oy...

"Paul's Third Law of Asking For Help
You will discover the obscure answer 5 minutes after giving up and asking for advice."

Turns out you set the column to "Display=False" but only if you are in popup or edit form mode, not inline.

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you did answer this yourself I thought I'd write an answer to clarify some things.

You can set the default value of the EditColumn to be false, even in InPlace edit. However it makes it a lot more difficult to save edited data as the InPlace edit (**for simplicity**) requires the EditColumn to display the save or cancel items.

That being said, you can do it - however you need to use ***explicit*** CommandNames on the items:

Say you want to **Update** a row with the new values you have inserted in the InPlace edit. Then the confirm button's CommandName would **HAVE** to be "*Update*" to be picked up correctly.

All of this being said, it would be a lot simpler for you to keep the EditColumn intact even when in InPlace (editmode).

Or you could specify the EditTemplate for one column to widen the column, add the two buttons necessary to perform Update and Cancel as well as hiding the EditColumn so that multiple InPlaceEdits can't be performed at the same time. :)

I hope this helps someone, as I was stuck in a similar situation myself when I had to incorporate both InPlace and EditForms EditModes on a single RadGrid and knowing the above information made a **WORLD** of difference.

Comment: Not sure that would have solved my problem, but  I appreciate the time to respond!  Thanks...Paul

Comment: Maybe not, but in case someone else finds this, it might help that person. 
I simply wanted to make sure people understand how strangely some Telerik controls do act sometimes when you aren't using it completely 'normally'. :)

Comment: Absolutely... and please don't misunderstand, I appreciate anyone who takes the time out of their day to reply!

Best wishes...

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
var agtype = $telerik.$(atCell).text().trim();

if(agtype == ""Guaranty""){{
       var masterTableView = sender.get_masterTableView();
       var columnIndex = masterTableView.getColumnByUniqueName(""Amount"").get_element().cellIndex;
       masterTableView.showColumn(columnIndex);
}}
```

Comment: Please consider editing your answer in order to have the [correct format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). This will make the code posted easier to be read. Also, please take the time to read the How to answer section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks! Daniel . I will see that